# Maven Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and would love some help with an issue I've been having. I am not able to compile one of my projects due to an Illegal Argument Exception for one of the dependency URLs. Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>MDM-Map-Reduce</name>
    <groupId>com.cardinalhealth</groupId>
    <artifactId>MDM-Map-Reduce</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>hortonworks</id>
            <url>
                http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/
            </url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hcatalog</groupId>
            <artifactId>hcatalog-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is the last few lines of the output from mvn clean install:

```
Downloading: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hcatalog/hcatalog-core/0.5.0.21/hcatalog-core-0.5.0.21.pom
4/4 KB        

Downloaded: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hcatalog/hcatalog-core/0.5.0.21/hcatalog-core-0.5.0.21.pom (4 KB at 28.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hcatalog/hcatalog/${hcatalog.version}/hcatalog-${hcatalog.version}.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hcatalog/hcatalog/${hcatalog.version}/hcatalog-${hcatalog.version}.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.895 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-13T17:52:15-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/12M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MDM-Map-Reduce: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cardinalhealth:MDM-Map-Reduce:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0.21: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0.21: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog:pom:${hcatalog.version} from/to hortonworks (http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/): IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 88: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hcatalog/hcatalog/${hcatalog.version}/hcatalog-${hcatalog.version}.pom -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

(I had to break the urls after http:// with a space for SO to allow me to post)

If you notice it seems like it is trying to pull the same dependency twice, I have no clue why it would do that, or why it would fail to resolve parameters correctly.

I have attached relevant files here, I am a complete Maven novice so I have included the directory layout (in list), the pom and the output of mvn clean install, both standard and extended (i.e. with -e for stack trace).

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_G2bKn27T9raFVoMkl0LUQyT28&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use pluginrepo instead repository

e.g.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```